# create a list with common head

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

How to create a list like below by `Table` `#&` or others?

```
    j1, j2, j3, j4 ... j15
```

Thanks.

Comment: Table[Symbol["j" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 15}]

Comment: Do you mean `{j1, j2, j3, j4, ..., j15}`?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Yes. RMMA has answered